# Syntax of Perl for loop

Tags: perl

I've inherited a Perl script, and don't have a Perl background (yet). The script is failing:

```
syntax error at /home/assay/assay/bin/mpprimer/MPprimer/bin/MPprimer_dimer_check.pl line 181, near "$k qw(a g c t)"
```

This is the relevant code

```
# create a binding array for each of the four bases
for $l (0 .. $pfl-1) {
    my $mbase = substr($fprimer_r, $l, 1);
    $primer_hash{$mbase}[$l]=1;
    for $k qw(a g c t) {
        $primer_hash{$k}[$l] ||=0;
    }
}
```

Any pointers or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put parentheses around the list being iterated over (the `qw//` construct in this case):

```
for $k (qw(a g c t)) {
```

Comment: Thanks, you are a lifesaver!

Comment: Also: Never ever use `$l` - its looks too much like `$1` and that's a built in. Actually - try and avoid single letter variables at all.

Answer (score 10):

You probably updated your Perl to 5.18. In that version the [qw operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.18.2/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) [was changed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta.html#qw(...)-can-no-longer-be-used-as-parentheses) to not behave like it was parentheses. From [perl5180delta](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.18.2/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators):

> #### qw(...) can no longer be used as parentheses
>
> `qw` lists used to fool the
>   parser into thinking they were always surrounded by parentheses. This
>   permitted some surprising constructions such as `foreach $x qw(a b c)
>   {...}` , which should really be written `foreach $x (qw(a b c)) {...}` .
>   These would sometimes get the lexer into the wrong state, so they
>   didn't fully work, and the similar `foreach qw(a b c) {...}` that one
>   might expect to be permitted never worked at all.
>
> This side effect of
>   qw has now been abolished. It has been deprecated since Perl v5.13.11.
>   It is now necessary to use real parentheses everywhere that the
>   grammar calls for them.

So there was a warning since Perl 5.13.11. If you didn't see it, it could be that you upgraded from a version earlier than 5.14.0<sup>*</sup> or because you never looked at your error logs.

The warning would have been the following, which is found in [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.16.2/perldiag.html) (use grep/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+f).

```
Use of qw(...) as parentheses is deprecated
```

<sup>*) uneven minor versions in Perl 5 refer to developer releases, even ones to official stable releases</sup>

Comment: Or because they skipped straight from a pre-5.13.11 version.

Comment: @jwodder Then they have one brave sysadmin. :) updated